# Unable to set configuration settings of embedded report in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, powerbi-embedded

I am trying to embed power-bi report with angular 7 , But when i try to set the configuration settings of the report it throws an unexpected error 
`Type '{ filterPaneEnabled: boolean; navContentPaneEnabled: boolean; }' has no properties in common with type 'ISettings'.`

My embedding code

```
var config = {
      type: 'report',
      tokenType: pbi.models.TokenType.Embed,
      id: <report-id>,
      embedUrl:<embedURL>,
      accessToken: <accessToken>,
      settings:{
        filterPaneEnabled:false,
        navContentPaneEnabled: false,
      }
    }
let reportContainer = <HTMLElement>document.getElementById('pbi-container');
let powerbi = new pbi.service.Service(pbi.factories.hpmFactory, pbi.factories.wpmpFactory, pbi.factories.routerFactory);
let report = powerbi.embed(reportContainer, config);
```

I also tried embedding in normal Javascript and it is running perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When initialising your config variable, put `as powerbi.IEmbedConfiguration` afterwards.